# How can I customize Android ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

How can I completely customize Android ProgressDialog? I want to use Horizontal Style but with AdMob banner ad or rectangle ad within the dialog. 
According to me, I have to create custom style and resource file for the dialog. How can I do that?

But I want the horizontal progress bar as it is.

Current code:

```
       progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading...");

       progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
       progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: use this great library. [material-dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

Comment: Thanks Vall0n. Is there any way by which I can do it without using any third party lib?

Comment: copy the code from library and customise it, simple

Comment: please check http://shweta-maaks.blogspot.in/2014/04/android-custom-seekbar-with-animation.html

Comment: Yes, i think so. But i don't know how and currently I'am having not engough time. But I would recommend to use this library for all of your dialogs. Because its so simple.

Comment: Sure! But how can I insert admob small banner? where to add the ad unit in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a progress bar and the admob view in a custom xml view shown using a alert dialog

```
       AlertDialog.Builder builderVal=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builderVal.setTitle("Loading") ;
        View holder=View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.your_view.xml, null);
        builderVal.setView(holder);

       AdView xs = ( AdView) holder.findViewById(R.id.admobView);
       //use your admob view
       ProgressBar pb = ( ProgressBar)holder.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
       //use your progressbar

        builderVal.show();
```

see implementation of progressBar http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/android-progress-bar-example.html#.WEKou-Z9600

Comment: Thank you so much Peter! AdmobView is giving me error. Can not resolve symbol AdmobView.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a layout and inflate it to the alertdialog by using setview method.Please check this link [here](http://islandofatlas.net/2014/03/29/android-custom-progress-dialog.html)

```
final AlertDialog  alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
        final View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null);
        alertDialog2.setView(dialogView);

        Button cancelBtn= (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.verifyBtn);
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alertDialog2.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog2.show();
```